# infix to postfix conversion using stack shows an infinite loop

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

below is the code of infix to postfix conversion using stack.The code executes an infinite loop printing *stack underflow* in one of the pop function ,i have tried commenting pop function call in right paranthesis loop but then there is no output, i am unable to find which pop function creates this problem . if anyone could help me find what the problem is it would be appreciated.

P.S. - The code works fine if i remove parenthesis from the infix equation that i am passing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct stack{
    int size;
    int top;
    char *arr;
};

void display(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if(ptr->top == -1)
    {
        printf("Stack is Empty");
    }
    
    else
    {
        for(int i = ptr->top ; i>=0 ; i--)
        {
            printf("Element: %d\n",ptr->arr[i]);
            
        }
    }
}

int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if(ptr->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if(ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void push(struct stack *ptr,int data)
{
    if(isFull(ptr))
    {
        printf("Stack Overflow");
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top = ptr->top + 1;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = data;
    }    
}

char pop(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if(isEmpty(ptr))
    {
        printf("Stack Underflow");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        char ch = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top = ptr->top - 1;
        return ch;

    }    
}

char stackTop(struct stack *ptr)
{
    return ptr->arr[ptr->top];
}

int isOperator(char a)
{
    if(a == '+'|| a == '-'|| a == '*'|| a == '/')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int precedence(char a)
{
    if(a == '*' || a == '/')
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if(a == '+' || a == '-')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

char* infix_postfix(char *infix)
{
    struct stack *sp = (struct stack *) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

    sp->size = 100;
    sp->top = -1;
    sp->arr = (char *) malloc(sp->size * sizeof(char));
    char *postfix = (char *) malloc((strlen(infix+1)) * sizeof(char));

    int i=0; 
    int j=0;
    
    while(infix[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(infix[i] == '(')
        {
            push(sp,infix[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else if(infix[i] == ')')
        {
            while(!(isEmpty(sp)) && stackTop(sp) != '(')
            {
                postfix[j] = pop(sp);
                j++;
            }
      
            pop(sp);
               
        }
        else if(!isOperator(infix[i]))
        {
            postfix[j] = infix[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            while(!(isEmpty(sp)) && precedence(infix[i])<=precedence(stackTop(sp)))
            {
                postfix[j] = pop(sp);
                j++;
                
            }
            
            push(sp,infix[i]);
            i++;
            
        }
    }
    while(!isEmpty(sp))
    {
        postfix[j] = pop(sp);
        j++;
    }

    postfix[j] = '\0';
    return postfix;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *infix = "(x-y/z-k*d)";

    printf("postfix is %s",infix_postfix(infix));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code stuck on `')'`.

Adding a `i++;` somewhere in the `else if(infix[i] == ')') { .... }`  block resulted in below.  Else code continues to parse `')'`.

```
postfix is xyz/-kd*-
```

---

How bug was found:

Added a debug print.

```
while (infix[i] != '\0') {
  printf("Infix: %d %c\n", infix[i], infix[i]);  // added
```

That led to see code stuck when `')'` was parsed.